# Unregister push notifications phonegap push plugin

Tags: push-notification, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a problem with push notifications unregister. I am able to register the device and get the token, also sending notifications too, but I would like to add the unregister feature too. Here is the code y wrote for it:

```
var unsubscribeNotification = function unsubscribeNotification() {
    try  {
        pushNotification.unregister(
        function(e) {
            //unRegister Success!!!
            alert('unRegister Success');
        }, 
        function(e) {
            //unRegister Failed!!!
            alert('unRegister Failed');
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        //Handle errors here
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

I also put a button to run the unsubscribeNotification() function when you click it. After a few seconds the application stops, no error, no messages, nothing!

I am using a Galaxy S3, I think it has Android 4.1

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?
I have the same problem - nothing happens, no event is firing.

Comment: Same here... still looking for a solution. I updated to cordova 2.7 and still the same problem. I will let you know any change.

Comment: Do you have any solution for now? Have the same issue.

Comment: I've found the following statement - "Unregistration may take up to 5 minutes to propagate" [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg) so it should work but slow.

Comment: I'm on phonegap 3.0 with PushPlugin 2.1.0 and I have the same exact issue. @lavrik, that it takes up to 5 minutes is irrelevant, in this case the app itself is simply stopping, but not crashing.

Comment: I am using the Everlive project with their sample application, and the PushPlugin from Icenium Graphite, working fine, register and unregister!